# Can LINQ GROUPBY and SUM with Dapper achieve this?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, windows-services, dapper

What I want to achieve is to calculate interest daily [DailyLoanCalculation] and at the end of the month get total of each account and save in [Total-interest] Table. The same thing happens every month

I have a table DailyLoanCalculation where I have daily interest calculated every end of the day. I have been able to achieve that.

```
    DailyLoanCalculation table          
Day    Account No   Loan     interest Amount Per day    
1         12345     3000       150  
1         23456     1000       50   
1         43567     2500       125  
2         12345     3000       150  
2         23456     1000       50   
2         43567     2500       125  

    Total-Interest Table            
Day Account No  Loan   Total Interest  Total    
30  12345       3000    4500           7500
30  23456       1000    1500           2500
30  43567       2500    3750           6250
```

Now achieving what is in [Total-Interest] is the problem.
This what I have worked on but couldn't go forward

```
 //Calculate the EndOfMonthDailyInterestCalculation
        public void EndOfMonthDailyInterestCalculation()
        {
            IEnumerable<DailyInterest> loans = null;

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                loans = conn.Query<DailyInterest>("Select * from DailyInterest where BackgroundMonthly is Null");
                if (loans.Count() == 0) 
                {
                    return;
                }


                var TotalEachLoanInterest = loans.GroupBy(x => x.LoanAccountNo).Select(g =>g.Sum(x=>x.AmountPerDay));

**//I cant go further at this point**

                if (TotalEachLoanInterest.Count() == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var loan in loans)
                    {

                        var SumOfInteretForTheMonth = loan.


                        var markDailyAsCalculated = new
                        {
                            amountPerday = loan.AmountPerDay
                        };


                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**If there is a better way around this please help me out**
Thanks

Comment: If the interest on a 3K loan is 150 a day, how did the total get to be 300 after 30 days? Is your total interest 30 * daily? Are these actual tables in your DB? Are capital repayments factored in anywhere? When, if ever, does it compound?

Comment: That's just an example. ```That will be 4500 in 30 days or 4650 in 31 days ```

Comment: But the problem with examples that are wrong is that we stand here trying to work out how to write code that does sums to match the examples.. And that's really hard to get right if the computer sums to 4500 and your question says it should sum to 300 - we can't know which bit is wrong. Please correct your question so that it's consistent with itself

Comment: When you say "I can go further" - did you mean "I can't go further" ? If you could go further, why didn't you?

Comment: @CaiusJard The tables have been corrected. Thanks

Comment: @CaiusJard I mean ```I can't go further```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement:

```
loans = conn.Query<DailyInterest>
    ("Select * from DailyInterest where BackgroundMonthly is Null");
```

After this statement loans is not null anymore. It may be an empty sequence, but it is not null.

**Improvement #1:** Don't test for the number of elements in loans. If the sequence is empty, the following statements won't do anything. Besides, why Count() all thousand loans if all you want to know is whether there is at least one loan:

```
if (loans.Any())
```

This stops enumerating at the first loan. Count() will enumerate all loans.

```
var TotalEachLoanInterest = loans.GroupBy(x => x.LoanAccountNo)
    .Select(g =>g.Sum(x=>x.AmountPerDay));
```

This is not what you want. You make groups of loans with the same LoanAccountNo. After that, you take every group of loans, take every Loan.AmountPerDay and sum them. The result is a sequence of Sums. You don't know the LoanAccountNo to which the sum belongs.

**Improvement #2:** Consider the [overload of Enumerable.GroupBy that has a resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__):

```
var loanInterestTotals = loans.GroupBy(
    loan => loan.LoanAccountNo,                // keySelector: group by same LoanAccountNo
    (accountNo, loansWithThisAccountNo) => new // resultSelector: take each loanAccountNo
    {                                          // and all loans with this accountNo
                                               // to make one new object
        LoanAccountNo = accountNo,
        TotalInterests = loansWithThisAccountNo
             .Select(loan => loan.AmountPerDay)
             .Sum(),
    });
```

Result: a sequence of LoanAccountNo, each with the sum of AmountPerDay. Note: the sequence has not been enumerated yet!

You have a table TotalInterests. Apparently you already know how to fill properties Day, AccountNo and Loan. All you want to do is know how to fill property InterestsTotal

I'm not sure if table interestsTotal is a database table, or a table in your program.

**Improvement 3:** keep your database normalized

I'm not sure if it is wise to have a separate table with these totals. If you do, you'll lose some database normalisation. Whenever one of the interests in one table changes, you'll have to update the interestsTotal table. That should be a sign that you have the same information in several tables.

If InterestsTotal is a table, consider removing the table, and create a Dapper SQL or LINQ query that fetches the information from table DailyLoanCalculations. Users of your repository class will not notice that the interestsTotal sequence is calculated, instead of a separate table.

If you really want a separate InterestTotals table, then you should update your InterestsTotal table and the DailyLoanCalculations in one SQL update call. This way you are certain that no one can get the updated value from DailyLoanCalculations, while the value from InterestTotals is not updated yet.

LINQ can never change the source, so to update TotalInterests table you'll have to enumerate. If you use entity framework, you can fetch all interestTotals that must be updated in one database access:

```
foreach (var loanInterestTotal in loanInterestTotals)
{
     // entity framework method: fetch the TotalInterestToUpdate with the same LoandAccountNo
     var totalInterestToUpdate = dbContext.TotalInterests
         .Where(totalInterest => totalInterest.LoanAccountNo == loanInterestTotal.LoanAccountNo)
         .FirstOrDefault();
     totalInterestToUpdate.TotalInterest = loanInterestTotal.TotalInterests;
}
dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

If you use Dapper you can probably update the data in one go. You know SQL better than I do.

**If InterestsTotal is not a database table**

In that case, consider a (Group-)join of TotalInterests table with the TotalEachLoanInterest. If you want in your endresult also the TotalInterests that are not in TotalEachLoanInterest, you will need GroupJoin. Otherwise a simple join is enough.

```
var result = TotalInterests.Join(TotalEachLoanInterests,
totalInterest => totalInterest.AccountNo,                 // from each totalIntere take the AccountNo,
totalEachLoanInterest => totalEachLoanInterest.AccountNo, // from each totalEachLoanInterest take the account no

(totalInterest, totalEachLoanInterest) => new             // when they match make one new
{
     Day = totalInterest.Day,
     AccountNo = totalInterest.AccountNo,
     Loan = TotalInterest.Loan

     TotalInterest = totalEeachLoanInterest.TotalInterests,
     Total = TotalInterest.Loan + totalEeachLoanInterest.TotalInterests,
});
```

By the way: did you notice I still did not enumerate any of these LINQ statements?

To get your end result, simple use ToList(). If your original loans sequence is empty, your result will also be empty. Therefore no need to Count() the original loans.

```
var endResult = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, very deep explanation

Answer (score 1):

I gotta admit, I'm slightly confused why you want to do this calc in C# when it looks like the DB could do it:

```
    public void EndOfMonthDailyInterestCalculation()
    {
        IEnumerable<TotalInterest> loans = null;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            //conn.Open(); //you don't need to open the conn - Dapper knows how

            loans = conn.Query<TotalInterest>("Select MAX(day) as Day, AccountNo, Loan, SUM(InterestAmountPerDay) as TotalInterest, Loan + SUM(InterestAmountPerDay) as Total from DailyInterest WHERE BackgroundMonthly is Null GROUP BY AccountNo, Loan");
```

...

Comment: How is this possible in the DB? How can I achieve this

Comment: Did I not give the code to do it in the DB? Look at the SQL... It makes a resultset that Dapper should be able to unpack into a TotalInterest object(s) but all the data comes from the DailyInterest table